# Drag and Drop ListboxItems in WPF

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, listboxitems

I am trying to figure out how to move the items in a pre-populated listbox with MediaElements up and down via mouse drags. I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend you check out [Bea Stollnitz's article on dragging/dropping databound items](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=53)

Answer (score 0):

With this dll:

```
 xmlns:ex="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"
```

You can then use interaction triggers and call your method in the viewmodel.

```
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
       <i:EventTrigger EventName="Drop">
          <ex:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding }" MethodName="DocumentListBox_Drop" />
       </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

And then in viewmodel:

```
 Public Sub DocumentListBox_Drop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs)         
        Dim droppedFilePaths As String() = TryCast(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, True), String())
        If Not droppedFilePaths Is Nothing Then
            For Each filepath As String In droppedFilePaths

            Next
        End If
End Sub
```

You should have this dll in your list of references already, if not you may have to look for it on google. Also Note: there is a little more to all this then what I just showed you like making sure allowdrop is set to true and so forth.